# How to read always encrypted data from Azure data factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I want to read always encrypted data stored in Azure SQL database using key vault and export to another Azure SQL database by decrypting created in the same server.
Is it possible in Azure data factory? If so what are the steps. What are the alternatives ?

Also I have read about using self-hosted IR on VM for this purpose. Is it possible to use Azure IR service in ADF Integration runtime setup? Since the resources are built on serverless architecture.

(PAAS) Azure SQL database A(Encrypted)  -> (PAAS) Azure SQL database B(Decrypt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADF to export Always Encrypted data from Azure SQL DB, but it requires a self-hosted integration runtime, and you have to use the ODBC linked service instead of the SQL Database linked service. You can use SQL auth or the ADF managed identity to connect to your database. You have to grant Key Vault access to ADF.

For more info, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#using-always-encrypted.

You could also do this in SSIS (which could be run in an SSIS IR in ADF), but it is [basically the same process](http://thewindowsupdate.com/2020/07/23/load-data-from-always-encrypted-enabled-azure-sql-database-using-ssis-in-adf/) and uses the ODBC driver as well.

Comment: Thanks @mmarie I have used Paas resources for this project. Therefore, is there a way to use Azure hosted IR instead of  self-hosted IR ?

Comment: No, but you can install a self-hosted IR in an Azure VM.